# How do I migrate a post with open bounty from SO to Android Enthusiasts?

Tags: support, migration

I have gone through similar questions on meta but as it's still not clear I am asking a different one.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767342/find-out-over-the-network-if-android-device-is-active) is a post which is completely off-topic. It's asking about finding an existing Android app and doesn't suit the Stack Overflow (i.e. site for those who code). It is best suited for [Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour). Futhermore it seems that it cannot be closed as far as there's a bounty on it.
I've tried to raise a flag -> select 'should be closed ...' -> select 'off-topic because...' -> 'This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network' -> !!! (I don't see Android Enthusiast SE site among options)

Can I migrate this post to Android Enthusiasts SE? If yes then how, if no then what do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you can do is custom-flag the question and tell a moderator it should be moved there. This is the standard procedure for off-topic posts which are good questions on other sites (which are not in the default migration list). And only moderators can close a question with a bounty on it, so that would justify the custom flag again.